# MySQL Join three tables and display 0 if null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables:

> person_table
>
> id|  name | gender
>
> 1  | Joe  | male
>
> 2 | Jane |female
>
> 3 | Janet | female
>
> 4| Jay | male
> etc...

---

> product_table
>
> id|  name
>
> 1  | magazine
>
> 2 | book
>
> 3 |paper
>
> 4 | novel
>
> etc...

---

> **person_product
>
> person_id| product_id | quantity
>
> 1  | 1 | 1
>
> 1 | 3 | 3
>
> 2 | 3 | 1
>
> 4 | 4 | 2
>
> etc...

---

I have tried to make a query that will return a table like this:
person_id| person_name | product_name| quantity
but i can't make it so that if lets say John has no books, it should display
(johns id) John|book|0
instead of just skipping this line.
Where did i go wrong?
here is what i managed to come up with:

```
SELECT p.*, f.name, l.quantity 
FROM person_product AS l 
INNER JOIN people_table AS p ON l.person_id=p.id 
INNER JOIN product_table AS f ON l.product_id=f.id
ORDER BY id`
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @KeyurPanchal i tried using left join and i get the same results as with inner join

Comment: You'll need to change the table order as well

Comment: @CD001 can you be more specific?

Comment: @Mike can you check my ans ?

Comment: Using `LEFT JOIN` the first table you select should be the one you **must** have the data from, `people_table` in this case, you then use `LEFT JOIN` to *attach* the other tables containing **optional** data to that one; so `people_table` > `person_product` > `product_table` : @knowledge.... has it in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're generating a report of **all** people, against **all** products with the relevant quantity; on a large data set this could take a while as you're not specifically joining product to person for anything other than quantity:

```
SELECT
p.id,
p.name,
p.gender,
f.name,
IFNULL(l.quantity,0) AS quantity

FROM person_table AS p

JOIN product_table AS f

LEFT JOIN person_product AS l
    ON l.person_id = p.id
    AND l.product_id = f.id

ORDER BY p.id, f.name
```

Which results in:

[image]

Is that more-or-less what you're after?

Comment: the result should actually be:
1 | Joe | Male | magazine | 1 
1 | Joe | Male | book | 0
1 | Joe | Male | paper| 3
1 | Joe | Male | novel | 0
2 | Jane | Female | magazine | 0
2 | Jane | Female | book | 0
2 | Jane | Female | paper| 1
2 | Jane | Female | novel | 0

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

you need to start with people_table than using left join you need to bring other table data.

as you need 0 value if null than you can use function IFNULL

```
SELECT p.*, f.name, IFNULL(l.quantity,0)
FROM people_table AS p
LEFT JOIN  person_product AS l  ON l.person_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN product_table AS f ON l.product_id=f.id
ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: somehow, i get the same result, row is just not showing instead of showing 0 :(

Comment: Might just want to clarify *what* `id` that's being ordered by, I'm guessing `p.id` otherwise it might complain about ambiguity - but this looks about right otherwise.

Comment: @mike can you show what result have you got ? and what is the missing

Comment: @CD001 if you have idea you can modify my ans

Comment: everything is being ordered by `person id`.
its weird that even if i run this query or the one i put in the question, the result is the same

Comment: basically, in person table i have a table with a unique id of all people, in product table a table with unique id of all  products, and in people_product i have the link between the unique id of a person, the unique id of a product and the quantity the person has of that product. If inside the database one product is skipped in the link table, for example if john has no books, the row with john's id, the book's id and the quantity(0 in this case) does not exist in the database and therefore is not shown after the query. I need the query to return a row with the quantity of 0, instead of nothin

Comment: @Mike - that's what *should* happen with a `LEFT JOIN` if you've got everything correct.

Comment: @CD001 this is exactly what i wrote in phpmyadmin: `SELECT p.*, f.name, IFNULL(l.quantity,0)
FROM person_table AS p
LEFT JOIN  person_product AS l  ON l.person_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN products_table AS f ON l.product_id=f.id
ORDER BY p.id`
and it skips the lines instead of ading 0

Comment: ^ you've written `products_table` rather than `product_table`

Comment: i think you want if customer has not order any product even you want to see it as 0 am i right ?

Comment: I think you need cross join with product.

Answer (score 0):

if has no book shouldn't appear in the table , try this (easy to understand) :

```
SELECT NAME
    ,'0'
    ,'0'
FROM person_table
WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT person_id
        FROM person_product
        )

UNION

SELECT person_id
    ,product_id
    ,quantity
FROM person_product;
```